# I ate so much, I must lie down

Tags: riddle, mathematics, word, rhyme

> So large I am, you could not see,
>   Bigger than aught that you could dream.
>   I ate so much, I must lie down,
>   To lay the weight off you again.
>
> You might think there's one of me,
>   A counter counted: there's more, it seems!
>   Lemon is Kate, by sight and sound,
>   But I can't fit inside your brain.

**What am I?** One very specific answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are

> infinity.

So large I am, you could not see,
Bigger than aught that you could dream.

> Infinity is larger than anything you can imagine. This is self-explanatory.

I ate so much, I must lie down,
To lay the weight off you again.

> The ∞ symbol is a sideways 8 ("ate").
>
>  "To lay the weight off you again" uses wordplay: "you again" is W, and removing the W from "weight" gives "to lay the eight". This is again referring to the symbol being a sideways 8.

You might think there's one of me,
A counter counted: there's more, it seems!

> This refers to Cantor's proof of multiple sizes of infinity (in particular, the natural numbers and real numbers have different cardinalities, and so the real numbers are uncountable).

Lemon is Kate, by sight and sound,
But I can't fit inside your brain.

> The ∞ symbol is called a "lemniscate", which sounds like "lemon is Kate". The last line is essentially the same as the second.

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Which bit was the giveaway? You've got everything perfectly except a subtlety in the 4th line.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I think I got the fourth line! Honestly, the *title* was the giveaway. As soon as I saw it, I knew instantly what the answer was. The rest just confirmed it for me.

Comment: Yep, you got the 4th line. Your green checkmark is in the post :-) And darn - I thought of the title first and built the riddle around that, but didn't realise it'd be so obvious.